# Where is the wireless connection wizard in12.10?

Tags: wireless, 12.10

I *accidentally* deleted my wireless connection, and now I can't find a simple wizard to choose my AP and connect to it.

The best I got was clicking the network icon in the toolbar and clicking "Edit Connections", but clicking "Add" in the Wireless tab prompts me for a bunch of information which I don't know.

The help file section on **Connect to a wireless network** says:

> Click the network menu in the menu bar, and click the name of the
>   network you want to connect to.

What is this menu bar of which they speak? I'm using Unity and I haven't changed much since installing 12.10, but now I'm lost.

What I want is a window that shows me all the wireless networks in range and allows me to choose mine, enter the password and be connected. That is how I set it up during the installation in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the network icon  on the top right of your screen, you should have a list of wireless networks that are in range.

If there is no list, you may see something like "Wireless is disabled". If that's the case, then open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and typr `rfkill unblock all`. This should re-enable your wifi and the lsit of wireless networks should appear after a few seconds.

See image below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I see now that my wireless is not working at all. The `rfkill unblock all` did not work, unfortunately. Do you perhaps have any other suggestions?

Comment: In a terminal type `lspci | Network`. Copy the results and **edit**  your question, adding the result.